# How could I append '\' in front of the space within a file name?

Tags: bash

I was working on a program that could transfer files using sftp program:

```
sftp -oBatchMode=no -b ${BATCH_FILE} user@$123.123.123.123:/home << EOF
bye
EOF
```

One of my requirement is I must have a `BATCH_FILE` use with `sftp` and the batch file was generate using following script:

```
files=$(ls -1 ${SRC_PATH}/*.txt)
echo "$files" > ${TEMP_FILE}

while read file 
do
    if [ -s "${file}" ]
    then
        echo ${file} >> "${PARSE_FILE}"  ## line 1
    fi
done < ${TEMP_FILE}

awk '$0="put "$0' ${PARSE_FILE} > ${BATCH_FILE}
```

Somehow my program doesn't able to handle files with space in it. I did try using following code to replace *line 1* but failed, the output of this will show *filename\.txt*.

```
newfile=`echo $file | tr ' ' '\\ '`
echo ${newfile} >> "${PARSE_FILE}"
```

In order to handle file name with space, how could I append a `\` in front of the space within a file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### THE PROBLEM

The problem is that `tr SET1 SET2` will replace the *Nth* character in `SET1` with the *Nth* character in `SET2`, which means that you are effectively *replacing* every space by `\`, instead of adding a backslash before every space.

---

#### PROPOSED SOLUTION

Instead of manually trying to fix the missing spaces, upon using your variable that might contain spaces; wrap it in quotes and let the shell handle the trouble for you.

See the below example:

```
$ echo $FILENAME
file with spaces.txt
```

```
$ ls $FILENAME
ls: cannot access file: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access with: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access spaces.txt: No such file or directory
```

```
$ ls "$FILENAME"
file with spaces.txt
```

---

#### But I really wanna replace stuff..

Well, if you really want a command to change every `' '` (space) into `'\ '` (backslash, space) you could use `sed` with a basic replace-pattern, as the below:

```
$ echo "file with spaces.txt" | sed 's, ,\\ ,g'
file\ with\ spaces.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked too closely at what you're trying to do there, but I do know that bash can handle filenames with spaces in them if you double-quote them. Why not try quoting every filename variable and see if that works? You're quoting some of them but not all yet.

Like try these: `"${newfile}"` or just `"$newfile" "$file" "$tempfile"` etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can further simplify your code if you're using Bash:

```
function generate_batch_file {
    for FILE in "${SRC_PATH}"/*.txt; do
        [[ -s $FILE ]] && echo "put {$FILE// /\\ }"
    done
}

sftp -oBatchMode=no -b <(generate_batch_file) user@$123.123.123.123:/home <<< "bye"
```

Comment: What does `{$FILE// /\\ }` mean?

Comment: @huahsin68 Replaces all spaces with `\ `.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to rename the file to work and rename it again after it has done.